how to assemble a second object from one
please tell me, there are two objects, a plane and a second object, in this example it is Suzanne, they have the same number of vertices, how to make the plane transform into "Suzanne"


You can't without cheating. The topologies don't match, meaning there is no way you can unfold Suzanne as a rectangular plane. Also, "transform into" is not clear at all. Your question will be closed if you don't give us more informations on what you want to achieve, what tools you want to use, etc ... We won't do this animation for you but we can guide you towards a solution if you give us more informations.

This is the situation, I need to make a drone show and I need the drones to be on the plane initially, and then take the places of the vertices from Suzanne

In this case, it is necessary to prescribe animation for each drone separately, or is there a way to do this en masse, and then adjust the animation?

So if I understand correctly, you want one object per vertex, and the objects should go from a grid distribution to a distribution of a Suzanne mesh ?

The Textools addon have a "mesh texture" tool that unfolds your mesh in the 3D space according to its UVs:

That being said, if you really want a plane grid as a starting point, then it's simpler to just make a shape key yourself and manually place each of suzane's vertices as a plane grid. Once that is done, you can animate the shapekey value, and it will waro the mesh from your original Suzanne you your plane grid.
